# How to delete all files in subfolders but not subfolders themselves via command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

For a given folder, I need to delete all files (various extensions) in all subfolders but not the subfolders themselves because I need to preserve the folder structure. Is there a way to do that via command line or a batch file?

Answer (score 6):

Run the Command Prompt and enter the following commands:

```
cd /D "your folder"
del /S /Q *.*
```

This will list all the files as they are being deleted.
To not see this, change the second command to:

```
del /S /Q *.* >nul
```

Comment: This is not limited to just the command prompt, it will work in powershell as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "Filepath" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} |
     Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

From powershell (or pwsh) you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

Comment: This exact command was suggested nearly 3 years ago